# how to save objects from a JSON in different documents with mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

Well I have the following doubt. I have the following:

JSON

```
[
{"name": "juan", "age": 10}
{"name": "pedro", "age": 15}
{"name": "diego", "age": 9}
]
```

User Schema

```
_group:{
type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
ref: 'Group'
},
name: {
type: String
},
age: {
type: Number
}
```

And I need to save or update this data in different docs with nodejs/mongoose. I planned to do the following

```js
var data = JSON.parse(json)

for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
var name = data[i].name;
var age = data[i].age;


User.find({'name': par, '_group': group_id}, (err, user)=>{
if(err)
next(err);

// if it does not exist, create new doc
if(_.isEmpty(doc)){
 var newuser = new User;
newuser.name = name;
newuser.age = age;
newuser.save((err, saved)=>{
})
}// if it exists, update it
else if(!_.isEmpty(doc)){
user.age = age;
user.save((err, saved)=>{
})
}
})

}
```

as you will see, the variables age and name within User.find remain undefined, so this does not work for me.

First of all, is it the right way to save this data? If so, how could I can use the for cycle variables (name and age) within User.find? If not, what do you recommend me to do?

Thanks,
Eduardo

NodeJS, ExpressJS, Mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one more issue which I think you are facing that you are calling a method inside a loop and it takes a call-back, so it doesn't wait here for coming back and move to second iteration, so you might face **undefined** and some un-expected behavior.

I suggest you should use **async/await**

```
  let user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({'name': par, '_group': group_id}, { name, age }, { upsert: true })
```

Comment: Thanks, Now i'm using async/await for do this instead callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

If you parsed given JSON well and assigned values to `name` and `age`, they are not `undefined` within `User.find` scope.

Did you checked those variables?

```
var name = data[i].name;
var age = data[i].age;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mongoose` [`findOneAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html) with the option `{ upsert: true }`.
This tries to update an object in the DB and, if the object is not found, it creates it. So:

```
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  var name = data[i].name;
  var age = data[i].age;

  User.findOneAndUpdate({'name': par, '_group': group_id}, { name, age }, { upsert: true, new: true, lean: true }, (err, updated) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
    else console.log(updated);
  })
}
```

The option `new` tells to return the updated object and the option `lean` tells to return a plain JSON, instead of Mongoose `document` object (the same as calling doc.toJson())

Answer (score 0):

Using the upsert option, you can use findOneAndUpdate() as a find-and-upsert operation. An upsert behaves like a normal findOneAndUpdate() if it finds a document that matches filter. But, if no document matches filter, MongoDB will insert one by combining filter and update as shown below.

```
 data.forEach( user => { 

     User.findOneAndUpdate({'name': user.name , '_group': group_id}, user , {upsert: true, new: true},  (err, data) => {
     if(err)  console.log(err);
        console.log(data);
       })

     })
```